# Mappik in Kaddish

Tags: grammar-dikduk, kaddish, aramaic, aleph-bet-letters

What is the meaning of mappiks in [Kaddish](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A9).

- ...יִתְגַּדַּל וְיִתְקַדַּשׁ שְׁמֵ**הּ**
- ...כִרְעוּתֵ**הּ**...
- ...מַלְכוּתֵ**הּ**...

Isn't a mappik in the word שְׁמֵהּ (for example) would mean her name. So who is *she*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Aramaic, the suffix "ey **h**" [means](http://www.vbm-torah.org/talmud2/04grammar.htm) "his." [In this context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaddish#Text_of_the_Kaddish), the antecedent is God.

Comment: I refer to this as "the rule of one increased feminization" from Hebrew to Aramaic. In Hebrew, masculine nouns don't end with a vowel (usually) and feminines end in "a"; in Aramaic, masculines are "a" and feminines are "ta". And so on.

Comment: @Shalom, that is not correct.  In Aramaic, the "a" ending is the definite article, and due to a quirk of language development it came to be appended as standard in many, many words. To return to Isaac's point, the suffix in jutky's question is the masculine singular possessive.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that it is a matter of Aramaic but was not sure.

Comment: @SethJ, _-a_ is both the definite article and a feminine ending. Feminine words that end in _-a_ end in _-sa_ when definite. So while Shalom is incorrect, it's only half the picture to say he's completely incorrect.

Comment: @msh210 Feminine words end that way when definite because of the way "a" became a permanent fixture of so many masculine words. It's a quirk of the language, but it's got nothing to do with feminization, and it has nothing to do with the Mappik possessive on the singular masculine. Some people mistakenly think it's a pattern (Shalom may or may not, I don't know); I'm just trying to set the record straight, since we're about learning.

Comment: @msh210 I think I misunderstood your comment. On re-reading it, I agree that the "a" is the feminine ending in Aramaic. However, I believe Shalom's point was that masculine words are feminized by adding "a". My point is that that is not correct. They are "defined" if you will, by having the definite article added to them in most cases, and because that is almost standard in later Aramaic, the feminine ending had to be adjusted to mirror the change and look like the feminine with a definite article. But the masculine words were never feminized. Everything shifted b/c of the definite article.

Answer (score 2):

Jutky, see my comment on [Isaac's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9831/mappik-in-kaddish/9832#9832). The Mappik Hei closing a Tzereh on the last syllable (ie., "eh" or "eyh", where the 'h' is pronounced as an exhalation through the mouth) is the masculine singular possessive in Aramaic. Although they have many similarities, Hebrew and Aramaic are quite different.