# Meaning of Mappik in יה

Tags: hebrew, words, names, grammar-dikduk, aleph-bet-letters

One more question about *mappik*

(I don't know what happened to me, but this topic somewhat disturbs me lately `:)`)

What is the meaning of the *mappik* in the following Hebrew words:

- יָהּ
- הַלְלוּיָהּ

I understand that הַלְלוּיָהּ is actually two words of הַלְלוּ and יָהּ, so answering just the first one is enough.

---

*EDIT*

In case the answer is that this non-regular mappik, but some sort of exception,
I'm also interested to know if this is pronounced as regular mappik or ignored (or something else).

Thanks.

Comment: I'll add a comment, rather than an answer, since I need to research this, but I believe it's a vestige of the case endings common in Semitic languages, which don't really exist in Hebrew, but which occasionally show themselves in certain "exceptions" that appear here and there.

Comment: I thought it was the way the Shem's first two letters had always been pronounced?

Comment: @JXG what shem exactly do you mean? Tetragrammaton?

Comment: @jutky, exactly. I don't have any proof, aside from academic views on how it was pronounced, which may well be circular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mappiq simply marks a ה which is a "real" *h* sound instead of a vowel *a* at the end of a word.

So, since יה is an abbreviation of the Tetragrammaton, the mappiq in יה points to the second letter of that word, which is a "real" *h*. (We don't pronounce that word at all, but that's another matter.)

Comment: Yud Kay is not an abbreviation of Yud Kay Vov Kay but a Divine Name Itself.

Comment: @yoel, it is and it isn't. It's an independent name of Hashem (with all of the halachos that pertain to that), true, but it is also a shortened form of YKVK (see Rashi to Ex. 17:16).